# Is there some existing tool to automate search for a full resolution of image, using search by image?

Tags: gratis, images, automation, search-engine, search

Currently I am doing it manually using Google search by image:

- Search by image using some existing small image file (with sorting results by image size)
- Select biggest returned image that have thumbnail exactly the same (or nearly exactly the same) as original image - to avoid related images or changed versions
- Download it and repeat using bigger image as seed. Stop on failure to find a bigger image.

It seems to be obvious task that may be easily automated. Is there some existing tool able to do this? Or free API allowing to make it?

I have no problem with writing some code to accomplish it but I am not willing to pay money for API/tool.

It is supposed to work on Ubuntu and/or Windows 7.

Comment: Please state that you are searching the web, not your PC (mentioning downloading is a clue, but it is not clear enough). Which o/s, or browser based? Free, or are you willing to pay. the more information that you give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: Manually, you can do it with https://www.tineye.com/ If you can code, then you can use their API. See http://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI

Comment: @Mawg At $300 as minimal price it would be cheaper to hire somebody who would do it manually :(